# STIX 2.0 font declaration

Tags: xetex, luatex, unicode-math, stix

Today the STIX v2.0 was released. What is the proper font declaration to make use of various optical sizes etc with unicode-math?

Comment: What's the basis for your view that Stix Two provides optically sized font variants (subfamilies)?

Comment: @Mico Was hoping for the best.:-( May I ask then, which math fonts do contain the optical sizes, apart from Minion Math?

Comment: For one, Latin Modern Math, a direct descendant of Computer Modern. :-)

Comment: @Mico How do you tell that? `otfinfo` doesn't seem to recognise it.

Comment: @cfr -- Give `\scalebox{2}{$\scriptscriptstyle aaazzz$} $aaazzz$` and `\scalebox{2}{\tiny Hello} Hello` a try. (Requires `graphicx` for `\scalebox` macro.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don’t need to do any thing to get the optical sizes included in the math font. They are associated with the `ssty` feature which `unicode-math` will enable it for script and scriptscript font sizes.

Comment: Is version 2.0.0 of STIX Math maybe still a bit buggy? `\scalebox{2}{$\scriptscriptstyle aaazzz$}` and `$aaazzz$` differ wildly in *size*, though (after further rescaling) not so much in the glyph shapes.

Comment: @Mico: All known issues with STIX fonts should be fixed in this version. The optical sizes do have weight and size differences, it might be subtler than in Computer Modern but that is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>[For your convenience:  You can download STIX v2.0.0 from [GitHub](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/)]</sup>

You don’t have to change anything because the release does not include optical sizes.  The new `ssty` feature which offers special sub- and superscript glyphs is selected automatically by `unicode-math`. See the release notes:

> ```
> WHAT IS NEW IN THIS RELEASE?
>
> In addition to the overall visual redesign, STIX Two incorporates a
> number of significant improvements and additions.  Special attention
> has been given to implementing accepted best practices for OpenType
> fonts, such as the use of font features to access variant glyph shapes
> that were previously only available via the Unicode Private Use Areas.
>
> The letterspacing and kerning of the text fonts have been
> significantly improved.
>
> True small capital variants (Latin, Cyrillic, and Greek), accessible
> via the OpenType font feature smcp, have been added for all text
> fonts.
>
> Text (lowercase or oldstyle) numerals, available via the font features
> pnum and onum, have been added, in addition to natural-spacing
> figures.
>
> Alphabetic superscripts and numeric sub- and superscripts, accessible
> via the subs and sups font features, have been added.
>
> Fractions are available via the frac feature, as well as numerators
> (numr) and denominators (dnom).
>
> The OpenType MATH table has been completely rewritten and extended.
>
> Additions have been made to these Unicode blocks:
>     Latin-1 Supplement          U+0080 - U+00FF
>     Latin Extended-A            U+0100 - U+017F
>     Latin Extended Additional   U+0180 - U+024F
>     Cyrillic                    U+0400 - U+04FF
>     Greek and Coptic            U+0370 - U+03FF
>     IPA blocks                  U+0250 - U+02AF
>
> Full details of included glyphs and supported font features are
> available in the included spreadsheet.
> ```

---

Addendum:  As pointed out by Khaled and misinterpreted by me, there are some optical sizes available in STIX2 which were not present in STIX1, namely for sub- and superscripts in math mode.  I misinterpreted this because for me optical sizes means the [Adobe definition of optical size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Optical_size).  In addition to Khaled’s answer here is a snippet showing the difference for sub- and superscripts in math mode while showing that there is no difference in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX2Text-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}
\begin{document}

\setbox0=\hbox{$abc$}
\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\copy0}

\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{$\scriptstyle abc$}

\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{$\scriptscriptstyle abc$}

\setbox0=\hbox{abc}
\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\copy0}

\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\scriptsize abc}

\resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\tiny abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What part of the text you are quoting says it does not include optical sizes?

Comment: @KhaledHosny Sorry about that, I clarified my answer.  I was (and still am) thinking of optical sizes the Adobe way.  For me `ssty` is only a font feature and not like the true subfamilies which are available for math *and* text in, e.g., Computer Modern.

Comment: For OpenType math fonts, the canonical way to handle optical sizes is through the the `ssty` feature. For text fonts you indeed need separate font files, and it is true that STIX does not provide optical sizes for the text fonts.