# Inconsistent script sizes with STIX Two and unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, stix

With `unicode-math`, it is recommended to use `\symup` to get upright symbols in math-mode, and to use `\textnormal` to get upright text, e.g. for text label subscripts. When using the STIX Two fonts, these two commands give inconsistent results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
\[
    \textnormal{AVfi}_{\textnormal{AVfi}_\textnormal{AVfi}} \qquad \symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}_\symup{AVfi}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

In the left case, we get nice kerning, and ligatures, but the font size in the subscripts are bad. In the right case, the font size in the subscripts is good, but the kerning and ligatures are bad.

I think the problem is that STIX Two Text doesn't contain the correct glyphs for optical sizes in subscripts.

Is it possible to get good kerning, ligatures, and sizing without modifying the font files? If not, is there an easy way to achieve the desired result using fontforge? I can live without the ligatures, if this causes problems.

Comment: Note, thet it's recommended to use `\symup` to get **symbols** in math mode, and not **words**.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I know. I only used it here to illustrate the difference in optical sizes.

Comment: in addition to what @SergeiGolovan says, there will *never* be ligatures among math symbols, at least not the "f" kind.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My intent wasn't to get ligatures among math symbols. I want to use `\textnormal` with the sizing achieved using `\symup`.

Comment: I'm not sure STIX Two Text has optical sizes for subscripts and superscripts, like STIX Two Math. It's easy to remove the optical sizes in the math font.

Comment: @egreg You mean like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341895/10995

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, that's it. The optical sizes provided by `ssty` clash with textual subscripts, because there's no similar adjustment for text fonts: geometric scaling is evil!

Answer (score 2):

Optical sizes for letters are chosen at certain font sizes *in math mode*.

Here's an experiment: you can see that the `+ssty=0` or `+ssty=1` features are not honored in text (second line).

What you can do is disabling optical sizes in math (fourth line).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}[
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={9-}},
    {Size={6-9},RawFeature={+ssty=0}},
    {Size={-6},RawFeature={+ssty=1}},
  },
]
\newfontfamily{\stixmath}{STIX Two Math}[
  SizeFeatures={
    {Size={9-}},
    {Size={6-9},RawFeature={+ssty=0}},
    {Size={-6},RawFeature={+ssty=1}},
  },
]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  version=test,
  script-features={},
  sscript-features={}
]

\begin{document}

AVfi{\footnotesize AVfi}{\tiny AVfi}

{\stixmath AVfi{\footnotesize AVfi}{\tiny AVfi}}

$\textnormal{AVfi}_{\textnormal{AVfi}_\textnormal{AVfi}}$

{\mathversion{test}$\symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}_\symup{AVfi}}$}

$\symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}_\symup{AVfi}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the font size used by `\textnormal` in subscripts is exactly the same as the one used by `\symup`; just add

```
$\textnormal{\detokenize\expandafter{\the\font}}$

$\scriptstyle\textnormal{\detokenize\expandafter{\the\font}}$

$\scriptscriptstyle\textnormal{\detokenize\expandafter{\the\font}}$

\detokenize\expandafter{\the\textfont2}

\detokenize\expandafter{\the\scriptfont2}

\detokenize\expandafter{\the\scriptscriptfont2}
```

at the end of the previous example and you'll see

[image]

The difference in size is only an optical effect due to the subscripts obtained with `\symup` are affected by `ssty`.

Answer (score 1):

Math fonts and math mode are designed for math, which means that they are mostly meant for *single* math symbols and not for text *words*. If you really want to print a word in a subscript, it would more logical to explicitly switch to text mode -- and in text mode you naturally can adjust the font sizes:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\newcommand\mytext[1]
{%
  {\mathchoice
  {\mbox{\normalfont\normalsize\color{green}#1}}%
  {\mbox{\normalfont\normalsize\color{blue}#1}}%
  {\mbox{\normalfont\footnotesize\color{red}#1}}%
  {\mbox{\normalfont\fontsize{5.5pt}{6pt}\selectfont\color{red!50!green}#1}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
$   \mytext{AVfi}_{\mytext{AVfi}_{\mytext{AVfi}}} \qquad \symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}}} $

\[
    \mytext{AVfi}_{\mytext{AVfi}_{\mytext{AVfi}}} \qquad \symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}_{\symup{AVfi}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textnormal` in math mode does `\mathchoice` under the hood, choosing `\f@size`, `\sf@size` and `\ssf@size`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but but if I understood the question correctly \sf@size is a bit too small for the OP.

Comment: No, it's a completely different problem.